# How to show first page of the route without page number on Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've been trying to create a blog page which contains pagination with numbers.

My pages folder is like below :

```
src
-pages
--blog
---[id].tsx
```

I am able to render all static pages with **getStaticPaths**  function Next provides.

The issue is I would like to show first page as **/blog** instead of  **/blog/1**.

How can I push the route **/blog** when there is **/blog/1** content?

Answer (score 0):

### There could be (1) client side routing and (2) server side routing

create new page **blog/index.tsx**

```
src
-pages
--blog
---[id].tsx
---index.tsx
```

and redirect to /blog/1 in index.tsx(**client side routing**)

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Blog() {

  useEffect(() => {
    router.push('/blog/1')
  }, [])

  return <p>Redirecting...</p>
}
```

**server side route**

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Blog() {

  useEffect(() => {
    router.push('/blog/1')
  }, [])

  return <p>Redirecting...</p>
}

export const getServerSideProps = ({ req, res }) => {
    res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/blog/1" });
    res.end();
    return {
        props: {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this approach but didn't like it. 
1 - It takes time for redirection
2 - The URL still shows /blog/1 which is not desired.